# How can I copy the web address of a javascript generated link?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to be able to link directly to the individual funds on the page at https://cfrrrscholarships.communityforce.com/Funds/Search.aspx

If I copy the link, it just contains the following code:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PreContent$GrantsSearch1$grdFund$ctl03$lnkFundName','')
```

Is there a way to enter some variables into the address bar to obtain a unique address for each of these links on the page?

Comment: The text you get is the href of the link. Only you can do, is to find `__doPostBack` function from the source, and check what it does with the given parameters.

Comment: The JS link there is submitted in a Form to the same page: `https://cfrrrscholarships.communityforce.com/Funds/Search.aspx`. There are no separate URLs for the different pages, unfortunately. Bad site design IMO - I think what you're hoping for isn't possible (at least given the interface of that site that I can see)

Answer (score 0):

You can't in this case - the javascript **pseudo protocol** in the link anchor tag's href value is being used to execute a function call (to `__doPostBack`) in the page you are looking at, and provide the arguments used to submit a form to replace the current page content with the server's response.

In other words the href value is not a url, and an `onclick` handler on any number of different element tags could have achieved a similar result.

What the server responds with is, hmm, best known to the server and doesn't need to have a url accessible from the web. (It may have one, but that information is not contained in the page linked in the question).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks to everyone for taking the time to respond!